# Is it possible to Scale a Container to fit inside another Container?

Tags: css

Over and over again in various technologies, a key piece of functionality is to take any content and fit it into any other content. It isn't a trivial problem and a few years ago I ended up with a very verbose JS solution which I am not particularly happy with.

I have simplified the problem into a handful of divs. The `inner` container contains a `top` and `bottom` container and now I want to fit that `inner` inside another `outer` container exactly keeping aspect ratio and centered.

Something like this.

[image: demo]

A basic template. One of the issues here is that I am not sure the responsibilities from a CSS perspective. I am visualising this similar to `object-fit: contain` the only difference is that I have a div container rather than an geometry object but seeking similar behaviour.

```css
html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0
}

.outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  
}

.top {
  background-color: #0ff;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}

.bottom {
  background-color: #0f0;
  width: 1000px;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class=outer>
  <div class=inner>
    <div class=top>
    </div>
    <div class=bottom>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the same Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yxho9n5a/7/)

**Edit**:

Just to make it clear that there should be no scroll bars.  `inner` can be anything of any size. It might have 1000 youtube embeds, or a 2000x2000 canvas game. But if `outer` is 100px x 100px then all content "fits into" that space.

**Edit**

Basically I want `object-fit: contain`. When you have a `div` and and an `img` inside. `contain` will scale to fit that geometry to the parent container. It isn't cropped, or resized. However, I have a `content div` not a Image. So how does one recreate the same behaviour?

Comment: Can you put your code in Snippet..

Comment: Is it OK if width of `top` and `bottom` changes to fit the container?

Comment: The Top and Bottom are kind of just there for content.  It doesn't really matter what `inner` has.  It might be this demo, or 1000 images, or a huge Canvas game.  Whatever inner is as a container needs to scale into outer. Things cannot resize but must scale without cropping or distortion

Comment: @user1059939 I posted an answer see if it helps you with your problem

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1 : Mobile Responsive

```
.outer{
  max-width:100%;
}

.inner{
  border:1px solid red;
  max-width:100%;
}

/*You can join both selectors in CSS with same properties */
.top,.bottom {
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
  border:4px solid blue;
  width: 1000px;
  height:1000px;
  max-width:100%;

  /*The max-width will make the boxes fit inside the screen (no scrolling for the width so no need to use overflow-x), but the divs will not be 1000px in case the containing div or in case the borwser window is less than 1000px*/
}
```

[Demo in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qfyr9Low/)

Solution 2:
/*Simple math with fixed sizes */

```
.inner{
   border:1px solid red;
   width:1000px;
   height: 2000px;
}
.top, .bottom{     
  box-sizing:border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   border:4px solid blue;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1000px;
}
```

[Demo in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/945rvfc2/)

Solution 3:
/*Use height:50%; as you want to divide by half, but not if you want to maintain the 1000px height,
In some cases you may need min-height:1000px; to prevent resizing the height less than 1000px;*/

```
.inner{
   border:1px solid red;
   width:1000px;
   height: 2000px;
}
.top , .bottom{
   box-sizing:border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box; 
   border:4px solid blue;
   width: 1000px;
   height: 1000px;
   max-height:50%;
}
```

[Demo in JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b54st8cp/)

Side notes:
You do not need to use width:100% and height:100% for the outer divs when you want to set specific size, unless you want to use mobile responsive design then you need also max-width, because a percentage is used to make the divs proportional either to the browser window or the div container.

max-width : 100%; to all divs (parents and childs) to become mobile responsive, so the width will be resized when resizing the window to fit,
box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing: border-box; to contain the .top,.bottom divs inside .inner div when you add padding and border to them.

Comment: Thanks for your impressively detailed answer!  I think I messed up my question however.  On JS fiddle, the render window is small.  My 2000px height `inner` should be scaled to fit inside the available space.  (There is no scroll bars).  If the `body` of the document is 100px x 100px.  There should be no scrollbars, but I should still see the `inner` content  (it is just very scaled)

Comment: Quote "My 2000px height inner should be scaled to fit inside the available space", 
So you can use max-height:100%; on all divs
       .outer,.inner.top,.bottom{
              max-height:100%; 
       }

Comment: I was playing with the JSFiddles for a while during lunch and I couldn't get the outcome I was looking for.  I tried add `max-height`, getting rid of `max-width` and so on but ultimately I still have scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Add `display: grid` to `.outer`

Look at this snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/yxho9n5a/31/

Comment: Thank you! I don't really see much difference from my original behaviour however.  In a fiddle, I would expect to see no scroll bars but still see my 1000x2000 content (only it is scaled much smaller to fit)